Docker image build Error 'SIGSEGV' at yarn build in yml
I've met problem when i try to build docker image.
My AWS ECS task architecture is linux/arm64.
If i build docker image on default settings of yml, then ECS task update failed.
Error message is:

exec format error

and i know reason that builded image architecture is amd64.
So i modified the yml as follows,
`name: CI/CD Pipeline
on:
push:
branches:
- main
jobs:
build-and-deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
env:
  AWS_REGION: *
  ECR_REPOSITORY: *
  IMAGE_TAG: latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up QEMU
    uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
    with:
      platforms: linux/arm64

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

  - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
      aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

  - name: Login to Amazon ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

  - name: Extract DEPLOY_PROD_ENV secret
    id: extract-env
    run: echo "${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PROD_ENV }}" > .env

  - name: Build and push Docker image
    run: |
      docker buildx create --use
      docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64 -t ${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }} .
      docker push ${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}

`
But i met error as follows
RUN yarn build ... error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV"
I tried many searches including gpt, but i didn't solve this problem.
How can i build docker image to linux/arm64 in yml?

This sounds like an error with a docker build, in a CI/CD pipeline of some sort, that has nothing to do with ECS because the error occurs before you ever deploy to ECS. Is that a GitHub Actions pipeline? Also, what happens if you try to build the docker image locally?

yes, that is a github actions pipeline.
If I build the Docker image locally, it works fine without any problems. However, a problem occurs when using a github action pipeline.

Since I use the M1 chip, my local environment is ARM, so there is no problem building a Docker image and using it in ECS. However, when building the image in GitHub Action's virtual machine, the yml was configured as asked, but a problem occurred.
